# AttributeError: 'kid_learning' object has no attribute 'MyText' in Tkinter app while using speech recognition

Tags: tkinter, speech-to-text, python-3.8

im trying to build a small project with speech to text and text to speech functionality. The speech to text function has an attribute error, this works fine when you run that block separately though, any help would be highly appreciated.

Please check the test_numbers function where the speech_to_text function is called.

Sample Error:-
output_number=tk.Label(self.window, text=self.MyText, fg='Black', font=("Helvetica", 16))
AttributeError: 'kid_learning' object has no attribute 'MyText'

Code:-

```
import tkinter as tk
import pyttsx3
import time
import random
import speech_recognition as sr
 
# creating basic window
# window = tk.Tk()
# window.geometry("624x650") # window size
# window.resizable(0, 0) # prevents window resizable
# window.title("Kids Learning app")


class kid_learning ():
    
    def __init__(self):
      self.window = tk.Tk()
      self.window.geometry("624x650") # window size
      # self.window.resizable(0, 0) # prevents window resizable
      self.window.title("Kids Learning app") 
      # self.MyText=''
    ## clear frame  
    def clearFrame(self):
        # destroy all widgets from frame
        for widget in self.window.winfo_children():
           widget.destroy()
        
        # this will clear frame and frame will be empty
        # if you want to hide the empty panel then
           
        
   ## this is the welcome page     

    def welcome_page(self):
        self.clearFrame()
        welcome_text=tk.Label(self.window, text="Welcome to Kid's Learning", fg='Black', font=("Helvetica", 16)) # welcome label wiget
        welcome_text.place(x=60, y=50)
        
        modules= tk.StringVar()
        modules.set("Select Any Module")
        module_menu= tk.OptionMenu(self.window, modules,"Numbers")
        module_menu.pack()
        module_menu.place(x=60,y=90)
        select=tk.Button(self.window,text='Select',command=self.number_module_page)
        select.place(x=60,y=120)
        self.window.mainloop()
        
   ## this is the number module page
   
    def number_module_page(self):
        self.clearFrame()
        welcome_text=tk.Label(self.window, text="Welcome to the number's module", fg='Black', font=("Helvetica", 16)) # welcome label wiget
        welcome_text.place(x=60, y=50)
        
        play_ivr_bt=tk.Button(self.window,text='Play IVR',command=self.ivr_numbers)
        play_ivr_bt.place(x=60,y=120)  
        
        test_bt=tk.Button(self.window,text='Take Test',command=self.test_numbers)
        test_bt.place(x=60,y=150)
        self.window.mainloop()
        
    ## this is the ivr for text to speech function
    def text_to_speech(self,Text):
        self.engine = pyttsx3.init()
        
        voices = self.engine.getProperty('voices')
        volume = self.engine.getProperty('volume')
        rate = self.engine.getProperty('rate') 
        
        self.engine.setProperty('volume',1)
        self.engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)
        self.engine.setProperty('rate', 140)
        self.engine.say(Text)
       
        self.engine.runAndWait()
        
    ## this is the ivr function for speech to text
    def speech_to_text(self):
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        
        # Reading Microphone as source
        # listening the speech and store in audio_text variable
        
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("Talk")
            audio_text = r.listen(source)
            print("Time over, thanks")
        # recoginize_() method will throw a request error if the API is unreachable, hence using exception handling
            
            try:
                # using google speech recognition
                print("Text: "+r.recognize_google(audio_text))
            except:
                 print("Sorry, I did not get that") 
    
        self.MyText=r.recognize_google(audio_text)
    
    def ivr_numbers(self):
       self.clearFrame() 
       welcome_text=tk.Label(self.window, text="Please Repeat after me", fg='Black', font=("Helvetica", 16)) # welcome label wiget
       welcome_text.place(x=60, y=50) 
       ## display text
       
       Text= '''
       welcome to module 1 please repeat after me 
       1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
       '''
       display_text=tk.Label(self.window, text=Text, fg='Black', font=("Helvetica", 16)) # welcome label wiget
       display_text.place(x=60, y=50)
       
       ## repeat button
       repeat_bt=tk.Button(self.window,text='Replay',command=self.ivr_numbers)
       repeat_bt.place(x=90,y=120)
       ## exit button
       repeat_bt=tk.Button(self.window,text='Exit',command=self.welcome_page)
       repeat_bt.place(x=90,y=150)
        
       self.text_to_speech(Text)
       self.window.mainloop()
    def test_numbers(self):
       self.clearFrame()
       welcome_text=tk.Label(self.window, text="Repeat the number that pops up", fg='Black', font=("Helvetica", 16))
       welcome_text.place(x=60, y=50) 
       number=random.randint(1,10)
        ## show number
       number=tk.Label(self.window, text=number, fg='Black', font=("Helvetica", 16))
       number.place(x=90, y=80)
       start_bt=tk.Button(self.window,text="Click to Speak",command=self.speech_to_text)
       start_bt.place(x=90,y=120)
       # time.sleep(10)
       output_number=tk.Label(self.window, text=self.MyText, fg='Black', font=("Helvetica", 16))
       output_number.place(x=90, y=120)
       # time.sleep(2)

       if self.MyText == str(number):
                 print('correct',self.MyText)
       else:
                 print('false',self.MyText,number) 

           
        
       self.window.mainloop()          
            

        

s=kid_learning()
s.welcome_page()
```

I tried multiple things like declaring the function globally, indentation etc. Didnt find any luck

what i want is, once the "click to speak" button is clicked the speech to text should activate and whatever is conveyed by the user should be captured, (then if correct print correct else incorrect)

Comment: Try uncommenting `# self.MyText=''` in `kid_learning.__init__()` - also, capitalize your class names ;) `class KidLearning()`

Comment: Ask yourself when is `self.MyText` defined, and when do you try to use it. You are using it before you define it.

Comment: The self.MyText should ideally flow from the function speech to text. I think the if loop is getting called before the function runs completely which is causing the error(i guess) ...not sure of a solution though

Comment: Hey all, just topping up again here, the issue is still not solved, any help would be appreciated..